# Apparent paradox for second order derivatives

Tags: partial-derivative, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be an open set and $u \in \mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$ a distribution such that $\partial_1 \partial _2 u, \partial _1 \partial _2 u\in L^2$. Thus we can write for every test function $\varphi \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}_c (\Omega)$ that :

$$\langle \partial _1 \partial _2 u, \varphi \rangle = \langle u , \partial _1 \partial _2 \varphi \rangle = \langle \partial _2 \partial _1 u,\varphi \rangle$$

Then we have : $$ \int_{\Omega} (\partial _1 \partial _2 u(x)-\partial _2 \partial _1 u(x)) \cdot \varphi (x) dx $$

Using the density of $\varphi \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}_c (\Omega)$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ we get that : $$\partial _1 \partial _2 u = \partial _2 \partial _1 u$$ (almost everywhere)

My questions :

1. Is this reasonement correct ? (I do think so ...)
2. It appears that it proves that for every function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that both $\partial _1 \partial _2 u$ and $\partial _2 \partial _1 u$ exist then $$\partial _1 \partial _2 u = \partial _2 \partial _1 u$$
   This statement is clearly incorrect (there is counter examples), where is the lackin my proof ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct : for every function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\partial_1\partial_2 f$ and $\partial_2\partial_1 f$ are in $\mathbb{L}_2$, the equality holds, but **as distributions**. This means that the set on which the two functions are not equal has Lebesgue mesure 0.
For instance, in the canonical counter example (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Requirement_of_continuity), the two functions only differ at the $(0,0)$ point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !